# Correct use of icons when displaying like/comment count on my webpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, icons, branding

I am developing a integrated social media newsroom (like http://www.otto.com/de/newsroom/socialMediaRoom.php) for a customers website (can't give you guys the link due a restriction). The Data is stored in the customers CMS system which gets it via the facebook Graph-API usin a cron (every hour).

As on the given example we want to display like count and comments count for every facebook post.

For that purpose our designers created the following sprite for active & inactive state for both displays:

[image: sprite for facebook like & comment display]

The thing is were not sure if were allowed to use this icons.
I didnt find my answer on the facebook branding documentation page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/branding) too.
The documentation only applies to "Open Graph Built-in Like Actions" which we dont have as we do not link to any action - its just a "dead" display of numbers.

Concrete questions:

- Are we allowed to use the icons i put in above?
- If yes, is there any official documentation for this?
- If no, is there any official documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation we came the to conclusion that there is no restriction for the use of the raw count data as long as its not linked (=not a graph api action link).